Neo4j Cypher query to filter path properties and return a key value pair
I am trying to match a path with a particular criteria. On the matched paths I am trying to filter out the properties that each relationship of the path has [???]. My query does not run. Can someone please debug the following query:
MATCH path = (n:UrlNode {label: 'H'})-[r:PATH*]->(m:UrlNode)
WHERE ALL(rel IN relationships(path) WHERE ANY(key IN keys(rel) WHERE key CONTAINS 'H'))
  AND NOT EXISTS { (m)-[:PATH]->(:UrlNode) }
WITH path, nodes(path) AS nodes, relationships(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH path, nodes, rel, [key IN keys(rel) WHERE key CONTAINS 'H'] AS filteredKeys
WITH path, nodes, rel,  reduce(acc = {}, key IN filteredKeys | acc + { key: rel[key] }) AS filteredProperties
RETURN nodes,COLLECT({relationship: rel, properties: filteredProperties}) AS relations;

I have built the above on the following query which works
MATCH path = (n:UrlNode {label: 'H'})-[r:PATH*]->(m:UrlNode)
WHERE ALL(rel IN relationships(path) WHERE ANY(key IN keys(rel) WHERE key CONTAINS 'H'))
  AND NOT EXISTS { (m)-[:PATH]->(:UrlNode) }
WITH path, nodes(path) AS nodes, relationships(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH path, nodes, rel, [key IN keys(rel) WHERE key CONTAINS 'H'] AS filteredKeys
RETURN nodes,rel,filteredKeys


I edited your question, and placed [???] where text was missing.

The only syntax error I can see is in your merging of maps in the reduce() function. Change it to the following:
reduce(acc = {}, key IN filteredKeys | acc{.*, key: rel[key] })

See the documentation on maps.
To set the map keys dynamically, you will have to use one of the map functions from APOC:
reduce(acc = {}, key IN filteredKeys | apoc.map.setEntry(acc, key, rel[key]))


Thanks for the query.It worked....However i am getting the map with keys as 'key' and the value.Can i change it such the key is the actual filteredkeys with its respective value.

OK got it. I've added a way to add map keys dynamically to the solution.
